# Shipping method pick up in store (Free) - Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

I need to be able to offer my customers a shipping method like pick up in store (free). How can I do this in Magento 2.3.1? Also, I have table rates configured with a CSV and I need to be able to offer both shipping methods, the pick up in the store and sending the order at the price agreed with the CSV (depending on the country where it is sent, the price will be one or the other)

Answer (score 1):

You could follow this guide from Mageplaza to create your own shipping method: 
https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-shipping-method/